# I'm getting the empty item instead of a conditionally created item from a map function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript2.0

In a Reducer of ngRx I'm trying to create a single item from an item matching an if condition, but getting the empty item instead. Please, help!

Here is the Reducer code:

```
on(rawSignalsActions.changeRangeSchema, (state, { rangeSchemaName }) => ({
...state,
engagementSignal: state.rangeSchemas.map(
    item => {
        if(item.mapping.rangeSchemaName === rangeSchemaName){
            let engagementSignal: EngagementSignal=
            {
                id:0,
                name:'',
                metaSignalName:'',
                rangeSchemaName:'',
                type:2,
                mappedGraphSignals:[],
                signalInputs:[]
            };
            engagementSignal.id = item.mapping.id;
            engagementSignal.name = item.mapping.rangeSchemaName;
            engagementSignal.metaSignalName = item.mapping.metaSignalName;
            engagementSignal.rangeSchemaName = item.mapping.rangeSchemaName;
            engagementSignal.signalCounts = item.signalCounts;
            engagementSignal.type = item.mapping.type;
            engagementSignal.mappedGraphSignals = item.abstractSignals.map(
              signal => {
                let mappedGraphSignal: MappedGraphSignal = {
                    id:0,
                    name:'',
                    totalValues:0,
                    uniqueUsers:0,
                    mappedAttitudes:[],
                    signalRange:[]
                };
                mappedGraphSignal.id = signal.abstractSignal.id;
                mappedGraphSignal.name = signal.abstractSignal.name;
                mappedGraphSignal.totalValues = 1234; //dummy values for now
                mappedGraphSignal.uniqueUsers = 1234;
                mappedGraphSignal.mappedAttitudes = signal.signalAttitudes;
                if (signal.numericMappings) {
                  mappedGraphSignal.signalRange = signal.numericMappings;
                } else {
                  mappedGraphSignal.signalRange = signal.textMappings;
                }
                return mappedGraphSignal;
              }
            );
            //dummy values for now
            engagementSignal.signalInputs = [
              {
                value: '0',
                count: 2376
              },
              {
                value: 'no',
                count: 3423
              },
              {
                value: '1',
                count: 1264
              },
              {
                value: 'yes',
                count: 5423
              }
            ];
            return engagementSignal;
        }
    }
)[0],
linkedRangeSchema: something  
})),
```

I want to get a single item object instead of an array, discarding the rest of array.
When I debug the App, after passing the map function, I got engagementSignal value as:

[image]

Comment: Why do you initialize property values to just set them right after? You should simply use: `let engagementSignal: new EngagementSignal();` or assign the item values instead of those defaults.

Comment: Ok Thanks, but I think that's not related to the current problem. Let me try, anyway.

Comment: @jcruz Thanks for your comment, I soved that unnecessary assignments as const engagementSignal = {} as EngagementSignal;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the filter on array, followed by map function solved the problem!

Here is the working code snippet:

```
on(rawSignalsActions.changeRangeSchema, (state, { rangeSchemaName }) => ({
...state,
engagementSignal: state.rangeSchemas.filter(item =>item.mapping.rangeSchemaName === rangeSchemaName).map(
    item => {
            let engagementSignal: EngagementSignal=
            {
                id:0,
                name:'',
                metaSignalName:'',
                rangeSchemaName:'',
                type:2,
                mappedGraphSignals:[],
                signalInputs:[]
            };
            engagementSignal.id = item.mapping.id;
            engagementSignal.name = item.mapping.rangeSchemaName;
            engagementSignal.metaSignalName = item.mapping.metaSignalName;
            engagementSignal.rangeSchemaName = item.mapping.rangeSchemaName;
            engagementSignal.signalCounts = item.signalCounts;
            engagementSignal.type = item.mapping.type;
            engagementSignal.mappedGraphSignals = item.abstractSignals.map(
              signal => {
                let mappedGraphSignal: MappedGraphSignal = {
                    id:0,
                    name:'',
                    totalValues:0,
                    uniqueUsers:0,
                    mappedAttitudes:[],
                    signalRange:[]
                };
                mappedGraphSignal.id = signal.abstractSignal.id;
                mappedGraphSignal.name = signal.abstractSignal.name;
                mappedGraphSignal.totalValues = 1234; //dummy values for now
                mappedGraphSignal.uniqueUsers = 1234;
                mappedGraphSignal.mappedAttitudes = signal.signalAttitudes;
                if (signal.numericMappings) {
                  mappedGraphSignal.signalRange = signal.numericMappings;
                } else {
                  mappedGraphSignal.signalRange = signal.textMappings;
                }
                return mappedGraphSignal;
              }
            );
            engagementSignal.signalInputs = [
              {
                value: '0',
                count: 2376
              },
              {
                value: 'no',
                count: 3423
              },
              {
                value: '1',
                count: 1264
              },
              {
                value: 'yes',
                count: 5423
              }
            ];
            return engagementSignal;
    }
)[0],
linkedRangeSchema: something  
})),
```